# Is there a way to know when I've reached the last record in a fields_for loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I got something like this:

**index.html.haml**

```
%h1 Products
=form_for @products do |p|
  %p
    =p.label :name
    =p.text_field :name
  %h3 Sales
  =p.fiels_for :sales do |s|
    =render 'sale_fields', s: s
```

**_sale_fields.html.haml**

```
%p
  =s.label :date
  =s.text_field :date, class: 'datepicker'
%p
  =s.label :amount, 'Amount Sold'
  =s.text_field :amount
```

This would print the name of the `Product`, and the sales contained in `Sale`. I'd like to know when I've reached the last record in `:sales`, so I can print something different.

I know the collection generated by `fields_for` has an `index` method, but I'm not too sure how to use it, or if this could let me know when I've reached the last record. I know I could check the amount of records before I enter the `fields_for` loop, and subsequently compare it to `index`, but is there a way to know this without having to do that extra SQL query?

Comment: What do you want to do there? Like, print totals?

Comment: Not exactly. This is just an example, but in my real application I want to change the class of a certain field (which will contain a date). I'd later pick this date through JavaScript to use it as a default value for the next row I create with the same fields.

Comment: hmmm, now that I think about it, I could simply put the class to every date field, and simply tell JavaScript to take the last one. I guess that's an alternative. I'd like to know how to find the last record though, could come in handy for other occasions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

```
%h1 Products
= form_for @products do |p|
  %p
    = p.label :name
    = p.text_field :name
  %h3 Sales
  = p.fields_for :sales do |s|
    - if p.sales.last == s
      %p This is the last Sale
    - else
      = render 'sale_fields', s: s
```

here you are checking whether `p.sales.last == s` to verify if its last record else render something other.You your own code and change it the way you need and let know if it works.

Comment: I get an error that `sales` is an unknown method, but I think it's something else I may have done. I'm currently in the middle of updating a lot of code, so as soon as I get back to this issue I'll post an update.

Comment: @user3209270 i assume that you have product has_many sales already present.So p.sales should work :)

Comment: It is set. It sounds logical to me, but my application doesn't seem to accept it. It is way more complex than what I explained here (I oversimplified an example to make it easier to convey my question). I'll look it up soon.

Comment: you can do it without f.fields_for loop and render directly inside loop using p.sales.each do |f| and then try this solution...will surely work :)

Comment: I'm afraid I should have explained myself better. This is an oversimplification to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. There is no sales, there is no products, I came up with these as an example only. My Models are substantially more complex, so I need to create a new routine to test it. Unfortunately, I found a better solution for my initial problem (not related to this question), so I put it aside for a bit. I'll get back to it later, but for now, redoing something like that will take me time.

Comment: I do appreciate your suggestions, however. I just have to get back to it with a cold mind before I dive into my maze of code.